# ActiveRecord :dependent confusion

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have the following AR models defined:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Act < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :act
end
```

What I want is if I delete a Venue or Act, any associated Events are also deleted. But if I delete an Event, the associated Venue and Act are NOT deleted. I've tried various `:dependent` variations, but nothing seems to be working.

This seems so simple. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I had to call `destroy` instead of `delete` on the parent object. The docs don't really make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Deleting Venue/Act deletes all events it had, while deleting an event has no effect on Venue/Act it belonged to.

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Act < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :act
end
```